# SQL Query combine two tables on existing of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Short: I want to check if a certain cell value exist in another table.

Long: We have an old MS-SQL 2000 server and a some newer SQL Server 2012. And we importing data from the old to the new one. Herefor we copy the old tables and convert those an put the values into the Item Ledger Entry Table. And we have a "check" table, containing the data already read into the Item Ledger Table.

Now we had some issues whit those copying and there are entries in the "check" Table of data that is not in the Item Ledger Entry Table. So we are missing some Data.

So I did a test and if I remove the entry from the Check Table and start an new import, the data is being copied to the Item Ledger Entry Table. So now I have to check for data that is in the Check Table but not in the Item Ledger Entry Table. Good thing is that we have one Primary-key, [No_] in the Check table and [Document No_] in the Item Ledger Entry table. And we have a time scale, started 19 November.

But how do I put that into a query? Must be something like this

```
select * 
from [Check Table] 
where No_ "does not exist in cell [Document No_] in Item Ledger Entry"
```

Comment: You need to do a join. But I don't now exactly how to do that for MS-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Chk.* 
From [Check table] as chk Left Join [Item Ledger Entry table] as ItmLgr
On chk.[No_]=ItmLgr.[Document No_]
Where ItmLgr.[Document No_] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two straightforward options of finding the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Check Table] ct
    LEFT JOIN [Item Ledger Entry] ile ON CT.[No_] = ile .[Document No_]
WHERE ile.[Document No_] IS NULL
```

or similar to the logic you have explained, but put into the right syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Check Table] ct
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [Item Ledger Entry] ile 
                  WHERE ile.[Document No_] = ct.[No_])
```